# Kolmogorov-Smirnov (ks_2samp) p-value not as expected - Wrong test or understanding?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, hypothesis-test, kolmogorov-smirnov

***Context***

I am using `scipy's` [ks_samp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) in order to apply the Kolmogorov-Smirnov-test.

The data I use is twofold:

1. I have a dataset `d1` which is an evaluation-metric applied on the forecast of a machine-learning model `m1` (namely the *MASE - Mean Average Scaled Error*). These are around 6.000 data points meaning the MASE-result of 6.000 forecasts using `m1`.
2. My second dataset `d2` is analogous to `d1` with the difference that I used a second model `m2`, which slightly differs from `m1`.

The distribution of both datasets looks like:

`d1`
[image: d1]

`d2`
[image: d2]

As can be seen, the distribution looks pretty much alike. I wanted to underline this fact with a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. However, the results I get applying `k2_samp` indicate the contrary:

```py
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp

k2_samp(d1, d2)

# Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.04779414731236298, pvalue=3.8802872942682265e-10)
```

As I understand, such a pvalue indicates that the distribution is not alike (rejection of H0). But as can be seen on the images it definitely should.

***Questions***

1. Am I misunderstand the usage of Kolmogorov-Smirnov and this test is not applicable for the use-case/kind of distribution?
2. If first can be answered with yes, what alternative do I have?

---

***Edit***

Below is the overlay-graph. Concluding from answers and comments on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423571/kolmogorov-smirnov-ks-2samp-p-value-not-as-expected-wrong-test-or-understand) I assume that the divergence in the "middle" might be the cause since KS is sensitive there.
[image: Overlay]

Comment: There is a big difference between "looking alike" and being from the same distribution.   For example, the distributions of `sample1 = np.random.normal(scale=1, size=6000)` and `sample2 = np.random.normal(scale=1.25, size=6000)` will look alike, but applying the KS test to those samples also gives a p-value near 1e-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted this question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423571/kolmogorov-smirnov-ks-2samp-p-value-not-as-expected-wrong-test-or-understand) and got helpfull insights and answers there (also note the new edit to the question).

Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) is very sensitive to deviations in the middle. As can be seen in the newly posted overlay-picture in the question, right there is some deviation. Presumably, this is the cause for KS to reject the H0 (= same distribution of `df1`and `df2`).

For a more detailed answer see [@BruceETs answer on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/423573/202010) who deserves the credit for this.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you used another model for `d2`, so Kolmogorov-Smirnov-test predicts that the second dataset's distribution is not the same as `d1`'s, even though it looks completely the same. 
Despite it's not a probabilistic approach, but you can consider using [np.allclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) to compare the two datasets.